# XSSFWorkbook make part of cell content to bold using apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

My project need is to make part of a string bold leaving any OR and AND like the below example.

**TOWING PACK 11** OR  **TOWING PACK 13** AND  **TOWING PACK 14** OR **TOWING PACK 15**

I tried to follow the reverse approach.

1. I tried to make the entire cell BOLD // This works
2. Then using RichTextString make "OR" and "AND" to normal Italics. //The issue - After the first "OR" all the rest of the string is formatted to normal format.

Output I am getting:

**TOWING PACK 11** *OR*  TOWING PACK 13 AND  TOWING PACK 14 OR TOWING PACK 15

I am using poi 5.2.3 and below is the code sample. Can anyone point out what is wrong here.

```
   CreationHelper creationHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
    XSSFFont fontBold = workbook.createFont();
    fontBold.setBold(true);
    XSSFFont fontItalic = workbook.createFont();
    fontItalic.setItalic(true);
    fontItalic.setBold(false);

    XSSFCellStyle boldstyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    boldstyle.setFont(fontBold);
    int startrow = 2;
    Iterator<Row> boldrowIterator = spreadsheet.iterator();
    while (boldrowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row boldrow = boldrowIterator.next();
        if (boldrow.getRowNum()==startrow) {
        out.println(boldrow.getCell(9));
        Cell boldcell = boldrow.getCell(9);
        boldcell.setCellStyle(boldstyle);
    startrow = startrow+1;

            String Featuredescription = boldrow.getCell(9).getStringCellValue();
            if (Featuredescription.contains("OR")) {
                RichTextString richTextString = creationHelper.createRichTextString(Featuredescription);
                String word = " OR ";
                int startIndex = Featuredescription.indexOf(word);
                int endIndex = startIndex + word.length();
                out.println("Featuredescription: " + Featuredescription + startIndex + endIndex);
                richTextString.applyFont(startIndex, endIndex, fontItalic);
                boldcell.setCellValue(richTextString);
            }
        } }
```

***EDIT***

```
        XSSFCellStyle linstyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        Font linfont = workbook.createFont();
        linfont.setColor(IndexedColors.ORANGE.getIndex());
        linstyle.setFont(linfont);
        Iterator<Row> linrowIterator = spreadsheet.iterator();
        while (linrowIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Row linrow = linrowIterator.next();
            Iterator <Cell> lincellIterator = linrow.cellIterator();
            if (linrow.getRowNum()==linrowcount) {
                if (linrow.getCell(13).getStringCellValue().contains("LIN")) {
                    while (lincellIterator.hasNext())
                    {
                        Cell lincell = lincellIterator.next();
                        lincell.setCellStyle(linstyle);
                    } } linrowcount = linrowcount+1; }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a simple regular expression to find all the occurrences of `AND` and `OR` (note the spaces included in these strings). Doing this lets you easily determine the location of each occurrence within the overall string (the indexes of where each word starts and ends). You can use this to set everything to bold (like you are already doing) and then set each `OR` and `AND` to normal.

My code assumes your test text is in cell A1 - and that is the only cell I test. You can add back your looping logic to handle more cells.

You will also need:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

I have added comments to the code to explain specific lines:

```java
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/temp/poi/rich_formatting_in.xlsx"));
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
CreationHelper creationHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();

Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
String content = cell.getStringCellValue();

Font bold = wb.createFont();
bold.setBold(true);

Font normal = wb.createFont();
normal.setBold(false);
//normal.setItalic(true); // uncomment, if you need italics, as well.

RichTextString richStr = creationHelper.createRichTextString(content);
richStr.applyFont(bold); // set everything to bold

String regex = "( AND | OR )"; // note the spaces in the strings

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);

while (matcher.find()) {
    // process each found group (one group for each AND and OR):
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        // matcher.start(i) finds where the start of the match is
        // matcher.end(i) finds the position of the end of the match
        // we can use these start and end positions to set that text to normal:
        richStr.applyFont(matcher.start(i), matcher.end(i), normal);
    }
}

// write the final string to the spreadsheet:
cell.setCellValue(richStr);

// write the spreadsheet to a file so we can see the results:
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/temp/poi/rich_formatting_out.xlsx"))) {
    wb.write(out);
}
```

The results are:

[image]

---

The regex `( AND | OR )` is very basic - it assumes every occurrence of the words `AND` and `OR` surrounded by spaces are what need to be adjusted.

Comment: More generally, you can take a look at more topics in the [help] for additional guidance on how to get the most out of this site. @prathibha

Comment: I am trying to incorporate this logic to the above code in Edit section but only one style is working, the cell either has Orange color or the bold logic. Can you please let me know how I can combine both the logics.  
@andrewJames

Comment: Orange was not mentioned in your original question. I think you are _asking_ a brand new question - so you should _create_ a brand new question for that.

Comment: sure, created the below question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75289315/xssfworkbook-make-part-of-cell-content-to-bold-using-apache-poi-with-cell-color - @andrewJames

Comment: Please also look (again) at the topics in the [help] to gain a better understanding of how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Am I missing something in the new question, let me know if I have to add more details to the question. Can you please help on whats wrong with the code posted in my new question.- @andrewJames

Comment: Be patient. I expect someone will help you.